# DirectX 10+. Copying a texture to a vertex buffer

Tags: directx

I need to use texture data as z-coord in my relief vertex buffer. So i need a way to transfer that texture data to buffer, or a way to reinterpret it and use as vertex buffer.
MSDN says ID3D10Device::CopyResource method args must be the same type. So I cant use it.
Now i have to transfer data to CPU and send back as buffer data, but this is so ineffective.
Can anybody prompt proper way?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't just sample the texture in the vertex shader?

Comment: The easiest way would be to modify the data before uploading either to the GPU. If they are already on the GPU, you could probably utilize a compute shader to update the vertex data. Not sure about the technical details, though.

Comment: @AdamMiles Thanx, man. I should do that.